# Don't understand why I get stack level too deep error

Tags: ruby

I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass < BasicObject
  class Error < ::NoMethodError
  end
end
```

and I have this:

```
def method_missing(....)
  raise Error
end
```

and I get `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` when I call a missing method. I guess that some recursion is going, but I don't understand why exactly and what is happening.

Can you please help me?

**PS**

```
class MyClass 
  class Error < NoMethodError
  end
end
```

This works well.

Comment: Are you doing it in irb?

Comment: Yes, I am doing it there.

Comment: It should work then after you implement `MyClass#inspect` method.

Comment: Still not working :( (I defined inspect to call to_s)

Comment: Did you try to change the name of your Error class ?

Comment: Yes, still not working

Comment: How do you call your missing method ?

Comment: @Faery you use `to_s`, which is also undefined.

Comment: I call to_s on an instance variable, for which to_s is defined.

Comment: @Nanego, I create a new object `obj = MyClass.new(some_value); obj.here_is_a_method_that_is_not_defined`

Comment: Where `method_missing` is defined? Is it inside the class `Error`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyClass < BasicObject
  class Error < ::NoMethodError
     def method_missing(....)
       raise Error
     end
  end
end

p MyClass.superclass # => BasicObject
p method(:raise).owner # => Kernel
```

Now `Kernel` is not present in the ancestor chain of `MyClass` class. Thus when you are calling `raise` inside the `method_missing` method,which in turn again
call `method_missing` method(Because `raise` is not a method of class `MyClass`,nor the owner `Kernel` mixed in `Myclass`,so `raise` method look up is failed,and causing repeatedly call to `method_missing`. Thus it results in error as `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`. I tried here to recreate the scenarios what you are facing as below :

```
class Foo < BasicObject
   def method_missing(name,*args)
       p "hi"
   end
end

Foo.new.baz
# stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Here also the reason is same.There is no `Foo#baz` method,so `method_missing` called first time. Now inside `method_missing`, I am trying to call another method,which is method of class `Kernel`. Now `Kernel` is not mixed in neither `BasicObject`,nor in `Foo`. So method look up got failed,and `method_missing` called repeatedly due to call to the method `Kernel#p`,and it causes the error. To fix this I would do as below :

```
class Foo < BasicObject
  include ::Kernel
   def method_missing(name,*args)
       p "hi"
   end
end

Foo.new.baz # => "hi"
```

Hope you got the point now.

Comment: Thank you. I guess this is fixed if we mixin Kernel or if we simply use Object instead of BasicObject